# css diffrent images diffrent widths

Tags: html, css

I made a comment system and there are profile photos next to text but when someone comments profile pictures' widths are changing--something like this:

```css
.container img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<img  src='".$row2['photo']."' alt='pp' style='width:6%' style='height:auto' >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `height:auto;`, this is happening. Try setting a height of `6%` also

```
<img  src='".$row2['photo']."' alt='pp' style='width:6%;height:6%' >
```

By the way you only need on **style** attribute to us `inline-styling` as I did in code.

Comment: Setting fixed heights isn't usually a good idea. If any of the images aren't square they'll be distorted.

Comment: You've hit on the actual problem, which is the duplicated `style` attributes. The second overwrites the first, so no width is set.

Answer (score 0):

try using pixels with width instead of percentages.

Comment: but they also should have same aspect ratios, or you will have to give them fixed height too, if you won't do that pictures with different aspect ratios will have different heights.

Answer (score 0):

The element `width` and `height` should be equal to make a perfect circle. Since the images have different dimensions, You can use the `background-image` instead technique

```
 <div class='profile-pic' style='background-image:url(".$row2['photo'].")'></div>
```

CSS

```
.profile-pic{
height:50pt;
width:50pt;
border-radius:50%;
background-color:#eee;

/*background image syles*/
background-size:cover;
background-position:center;
background-repeat:no-repeat;

}
```